# Rails prints help for any command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

No matter what command I run I get the following output. My path seems to be correct. I have no idea what is going on. I just added ruby-1.9.3-p448 to rvm but I think this problem started when I upgraded to OS X 10.9. Please help:

```
Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]

Options:
  -r, [--ruby=PATH]              # Path to the Ruby binary of your choice
                                 # Default: /Users/markrusson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby
  -b, [--builder=BUILDER]        # Path to a application builder (can be a filesystem path or URL)
  -m, [--template=TEMPLATE]      # Path to an application template (can be a filesystem path or URL)
      [--skip-gemfile]           # Don't create a Gemfile
      [--skip-bundle]            # Don't run bundle install
  -G, [--skip-git]               # Skip Git ignores and keeps
  -O, [--skip-active-record]     # Skip Active Record files
  -S, [--skip-sprockets]         # Skip Sprockets files
  -d, [--database=DATABASE]      # Preconfigure for selected database (options: mysql/oracle/postgresql/sqlite3/frontbase/ibm_db/sqlserver/jdbcmysql/jdbcsqlite3/jdbcpostgresql/jdbc)
                                 # Default: sqlite3
  -j, [--javascript=JAVASCRIPT]  # Preconfigure for selected JavaScript library
                                 # Default: jquery
  -J, [--skip-javascript]        # Skip JavaScript files
      [--dev]                    # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to your Rails checkout
      [--edge]                   # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to Rails repository
  -T, [--skip-test-unit]         # Skip Test::Unit files
      [--old-style-hash]         # Force using old style hash (:foo => 'bar') on Ruby >= 1.9

Runtime options:
  -f, [--force]    # Overwrite files that already exist
  -p, [--pretend]  # Run but do not make any changes
  -q, [--quiet]    # Suppress status output
  -s, [--skip]     # Skip files that already exist

Rails options:
  -h, [--help]     # Show this help message and quit
  -v, [--version]  # Show Rails version number and quit

Description:
    The 'rails new' command creates a new Rails application with a default
    directory structure and configuration at the path you specify.

    You can specify extra command-line arguments to be used every time
    'rails new' runs in the .railsrc configuration file in your home directory.

    Note that the arguments specified in the .railsrc file don't affect the
    defaults values shown above in this help message.

Example:
    rails new ~/Code/Ruby/weblog

    This generates a skeletal Rails installation in ~/Code/Ruby/weblog.
    See the README in the newly created application to get going.
```

Comment: What commands exactly you are trying to run?

Comment: This is the exact expected output from running `rails new -h` so your rails command does seem to be running correctly.

Comment: If I run "rails g controller Contacts", or rails g model contact, or try to start the server with "rails s" or "rails server", etc. I get this same output every time. So what did I do wrong?

Comment: Are you actually in your rails application directory when you type the commands?  If you run `rails s` in a directory with no rails application you'll see the `rails new -h` as you are getting.

Comment: First check `rails -v`, gives a rails version in your folder.

Answer (score 2):

For rails 4.0.1, you might be missing your "bin" directory within the created project.  Create a new project, and copy the "bin" directory from that one.